# How do I count all votes for acts as votable gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Basically everything is in the question. How to count efficiently all votes submitted in the app?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: The simplest to do is Vote.count, but there is no model to votes table. I am new to rails and decided to ask.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ya gotta remember that the gem has it's own namespace and the class in that namespace is `Vote` - so you can get the count with

`ActsAsVotable::Vote.count`

The same goes with the acts as messageable gem, though the acts as commentable gem just uses `Comment` to simplify things, sort of authors preference, but if you open up the gem and look at the source files you can almost always quickly find the info you're after.